# Starcraft 2 with Wine 1.7.44; Cannot type

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

I just followed this [link](http://www.nosuchthingastwo.com/blog/2014/04/28/starcraft-ii-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

and installed starcraft 2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The game starts with no problems. But when it comes to naming my character, I am unable to type any characters into the textbox.

If I chose to skip that, the next step asks me for my battle.net ID (although I am already logged in). Also here I am unable to type anything.

I am really new to Linux. Will appreciate any insight greatly.

Thanks!

Comment: This could just be a bug in the game.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Well, that was the first link that came up about Starcraft and ubuntu! Can I (theoritically) play any windows game using Wine?

Answer (score 1):

Try other (older/newer) Wine versions. Some programs work better with different versions of Wine than the ones provided by APT. Various versions of Wine can be easily managed with PlayOnLinux.

To install POL, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

PlayOnLinux brings installation scripts for various pieces of software. Unfortunately, Starcraft 2 doesn't have an entry there, so you can install it using the 'Install a non-listed program' in the installation dialog. Should a script be added, feel free to use it.

You can manage Wine versions from the *Tools* → *Manage Wine versions*.

Looking into the [WineHQ App database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882), I can see that the version 1.7.44 has been reported to work the best.

Comment: Right! The link I mentioned pointed to a older version of Wine (1.6 something). I was having other problems till I updated to the latest 1.7.44!  And as no one else is complaining I guess I am doing something wrong. But will try this out. Thanks for the quick reply, the_Seppi!